# Using Functions From One Plugin In Another WordPress jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Here is the code from my events plugin that I need to re-use in my custom plugin.

I am trying to call this function from my own custom plugin. When the user clicks a button, I want it to call the following function.

```
my.render_fields = function( ticket_id, num ) {
    var $row = $( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta' ).filter( '[data-ticket-id="' + ticket_id + '"]' );
    var $template = $row.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-fields-tpl' );
    var $fields = $row.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-fields' );
    var template_html = $template.html();

    if ( ! my.has_meta_fields( ticket_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    var current_count = $fields.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-attendee' ).length;
    var diff = 0;

    if ( current_count > num ) {
        diff = current_count - num;

        $fields.find( '.tribe-event-tickets-plus-meta-attendee:nth-last-child(-n+' + diff + ')' ).remove();
        return;
    }

    diff = num - current_count;

    var i = 0;
    for ( ; i < diff; i++ ) {
        var tweaked_template_html = template_html;
        tweaked_template_html = template_html.replace( /tribe-tickets-meta\[\]/g, 'tribe-tickets-meta[' + ticket_id + '][' + ( current_count + i + 1 ) + ']' );
        tweaked_template_html = tweaked_template_html.replace( /tribe-tickets-meta_([a-z0-9\-]+)_/g, 'tribe-tickets-meta_$1_' + ( current_count + i + 1 ) + '_' );
        $fields.append( tweaked_template_html );
    }
};
```

I'm not sure how I get the .js file in my plugin to speak to that code so that it can use it.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above code is from other plugin ? if they have added it through .js file look in their plugin how they have enqueued that. There will be a function enque_script(). Now in your plugin check whether var 'my' defined or not. If not that means the js is not loaded, then just load that js using enque_script() function.